# Inconsistency/Differenct Voltage Each Output Op Amp LM324

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier

[image]

I use Arduino Pin to make PWM and give input to Op Amp LM324.

I would like to know, why my op amp has difference output. I have gain 2x. I multiply input from 0-5 Volt to 0-10 Volt because the gain is 2x. Output Pin 1,7, 14 is okay (has similar voltage).

But in output pin 8. It has different voltage almost 1 Volt. Let say Max Output for Pin 1,7,14 is 10.00. Then, pin 8 has around 9.1 Voltage.

How could be like that? I try to change my IC with new one. And has some problem. Why does it go?

My circuit is okay also. I double check my circuit.

**Edit** (Attach circuit)

[image]

**RG = RF = 100 kOhm**

**Vin = 0-5 Volt**

**Vout = 0-10 Volt**

I ground all of in one point. Also with Ground of Arduino. All of other 3 op-am is typically same circuit as above.

Comment: *"My circuit is okay also"* No **you think** it is OK. That doesn't mean it **is** OK. Maybe it just doesn't work as you expect, maybe your expectation is wrong. Still, you **have** to show the circuit. You will get no usable answers without it. I am too lazy to read: pin 1 = bla V, pin 2 = bla V and many others with me.

Comment: It's all about the circuit... and the supplies... and the load.... and the bypass capacitors.... yep all about the circuit.. just totally guessing it's one of these.

Comment: oke. thank you for you answer guys. I only use a 2 resistor each op amp. That is why I said my circuit ok. But I will change my resistor to other one, and recheck my soldering, my input. For the load, I havent put any load. I just tested the voltage.

Comment: Without the schematic, how can we help you. "I only use a 2 resistor each op amp. That is why I said my circuit ok." There are a whole lot of ways to attach two resistors to an op-amp and make a circuit that doesn't work.

Comment: I already update with my circuit. What kind of possibility due of this weird behavior?

Comment: That is not your circuit. That is possibly a small part of your circuit. If you want useful help, show us the *WHOLE* circuit, including power supplies, loads, decoupling capacitors (because of course you have those don't you), etc.

Comment: sorry i don't use any of capacitors. Just like that. No load. It looks like my soldering not good, because I have tried at the breadboard and everything is work. All 4 output give same value of voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The op-amps on an LM324 chip are essentially identical to each other (differences would be in mV) and you've swapped the chip so your circuit implementation **must** be faulty. So maybe you have a wrong or defective resistor or some conductive stuff on the PCB or you have a capacitor on the output that you **think** doesn't matter - whatever it is is something you have done.